# Catel framework - freeze while sending message

Tags: .net, wpf, catel

I have problem with Catel framework and `MessageBase` object.

Application freezes at line:

```
BalanceChangedMessage.SendWith(editedVisit.VisitModel.Patient);
```

in certain situations. I think, it happens when other messages are sent on other threads, but I'm not sure.

It looks like application cannot execute this line of code (debugger hangs on this line).

Any idea what I should do to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the receiving end that causes a deadlock. Make sure to dispatcher if required and double check your locking mechanism.